# Which would be the better choice – "appraisal" or "review" (or something else)?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

When an organisation is applying for a licence for starting a school/educating pupils/awarding nationally valid grades, it is investigated by the authority awarding the license. What would be the better word for this investigation – *review* or *appraisal*? I have checked various dictionaries, and from those I get the impression that *appraisal* is used more in the sense of 'evaluation', and that *review* is closer to what I'm after, but my boss says that I should use *appraisal*.

What would you use – *appraisal* or *review*? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather blurry distinction between the two, and they're often used interchangeably. *Appraisal* is usually used in the sense of "evaluation" or more broadly determining how much something is worth and how good it is, while *review* usually implies making sure something meets some particular standards and trying to find areas for improvement.

But it's not a hard rule, and in many contexts those definitions will either overlap (eg. a *performance review* of an employee and a *performance appraisal* are essentially the same thing), or one of them will be idiomatic (eg. you'd always *review*, not *appraise* a movie).

In your case, while *review* is probably the more precise word to use, your boss might prefer *appraisal* because it has more positive connotations. As an employee, I'd be more scared of a *performance review* than a *performance appraisal* - I associate *reviews* with making sure I meet expectations and standards, and *appraisals* with determining how much value I bring.

If you want a more precise (and more terrifying) word, I'd consider *audit* - this makes it very clear that the authority is formally verifying that you're meeting its particular set of standards for the license.

And, of course, it's possible that there's already an established, specific legal term (or an official English translation of it) for the exact process you're going through, in which case you should use it.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! Truly helpful!